# Reverse order of a rotation matrix

Tags: java, opengl, matrix, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm making a small test mod in Minecraft where a player can fly a small plane around in free space.

Minecraft applies camera transformations as

```
glRotatef(pitch, 0, 0, 1);
glRotatef(yaw, 0, 1, 0);
glRotatef(roll, 1, 0, 0);
```

However, with this setup, roll is applied *last*, which ends up making the plane tilt with pitch in world space, and not after roll is applied, making banking impossible.

I've figured out that to make banking work, I should apply the transforms in the reverse order, i.e.

```
glRotatef(roll, 1, 0, 0);
glRotatef(yaw, 0, 1, 0);
glRotatef(pitch, 0, 0, 1);
```

Is there some way, given roll, yaw and pitch, in *that order*, to get corrected values to plug back into the original Minecraft camera transformation to achieve the same final rotation (basically, make the plane rotate using it's own relative axes instead of the world axes)?

Comment: It can be done, but chances are it won't turn out to be what you want. Just to be clear, given three parameters for roll-then-yaw-then-pitch, you want to calculate three parameters for pitch-then-yaw-then-roll which will yield the same orientation, is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably want to maintain the rotation of your camera in a different representation anyway (either as a quaternion or a rotation matrix). This way, you can just add another rotation to it and don't need to bother what axis it rotates about. It will always be in the plane's local coordinate system (if done correctly).

Once you have decided for a representation, you can then convert this back to Euler angles, e.g. [convert quaternions to Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles). You should be aware of the rotation order of the angles. Since there are a couple of options, you need the conversion that fits your order.